# Find minimum value of $\cos\alpha$, given $\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma=1$ and $\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma=1$

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

Here is a problem I need help doing - once again, an approach would be fine:

> What is the minimum possible value of $\cos(\alpha)$ given that,
>   $$ \sin(\alpha)+\sin(\beta)+\sin(\gamma)=1 $$
>   $$ \cos(\alpha)+\cos(\beta)+\cos(\gamma)=1 $$
>   The minimum value can be expressed as $-a/b-\sqrt{c}/d$, where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, and $c$ isn't divisible by any primes $d$ is divisible by. Find $a+b+c+d$.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I need help on approaching it. I don't really know how to manipulate the two equations.

Comment: You can add where the question is from (seems like Brilliant). There are other ways to show [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), not just including your own work.

Comment: Try starting with $(\sin a + \sin b + \sin c)^2 + (\cos a + \cos b + \cos c)^2$ so that you have $\cos(a-b) + \cos(b-c) + \cos(c-a) = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 13):

Rearrange the two given equations,

$$ \sin\beta+\sin\gamma=1-\sin\alpha $$
$$ \cos\beta+\cos\gamma=1 -\cos\alpha$$

and square their both sides,

$$\sin^2\beta+\sin^2\gamma+2\sin\beta\sin\gamma = 1-2\sin\alpha+\sin^2\alpha\tag{1}$$
$$\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma+2\cos\beta\cos\gamma = 1-2\cos\alpha+\cos^2\alpha\tag{2}$$

From (1) + (2),

$$2+2\cos(\beta-\gamma)=3-2(\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha)$$

or,

$$\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha =\frac 12 [1-2\cos(\beta-\gamma)]$$

$\cos\alpha$ takes the minimum value when $\cos(\beta-\gamma)=1$. Thus,

$$\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha =-\frac 12$$

Solve to get,

$$\cos\alpha = \frac{-1-\sqrt{7}}{4}$$

Therefore, $a+b+c+d=16$.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, we have that

$$\cos x+\cos y+\cos z=1$$
$$i\sin x+i\sin y+i\sin z=i $$

and summing up by Euler's identity we obtain

$$e^{ix}+e^{iy}+e^{iz}=\sqrt 2 e^{i\frac \pi 4} \iff e^{i\left(x-\frac \pi 4\right)}+ e^{i\left(y-\frac \pi 4\right)}+ e^{i\left(z-\frac \pi 4\right)}=\sqrt 2$$

which, in order to maximize one angle, has the following nice geometrical intepretation

[image]

which, by cosine law, leads to

$$(1+1)^2=1^2+(\sqrt 2)^2-2\cdot 1\cdot \sqrt 2 \cdot \cos \left(x-\frac \pi 4\right)$$

$$\iff x-\frac \pi 4 = \arccos\left(-\frac1{2\sqrt 2}\right)$$

and then, by addition formula

$$\cos x= \cos \left( \arccos\left(-\frac1{2\sqrt 2}\right)+\frac \pi 4 \right)=\\=-\frac1{2\sqrt 2}\cdot\frac {\sqrt 2} 2 - \frac {\sqrt 7}{2\sqrt 2} \cdot \frac {\sqrt 2} 2 =\frac{-1-\sqrt{7}}{4}\approx -0.91143\dots$$

Here is a nice [Geogebra demonstration](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/ybqm3trz) of the logic prepared by user [Semiclassical](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/137524/semiclassical).

Comment: @ User can u give a bit explanation what was the construction and why one angle maximize condition? Cant there be a case that for minima of cosx , there r two cosx and cos y gets minimum at same point ?

Comment: I thought of them as complex numbers in a argand plane from origin at unit distance , but in the construction there r not focussed at same origin isnt ? ( In the previous post i meant minima arrived maybe when two angle are largest and equal , its possible right ?)

Comment: @Paracetamol Yes the geometrical derivation is derived by analogy of complex numbers (in the Argand's plane) and vectors. The sum of the three unitary vectors must be equal to $\sqrt 2$ and, in order to maximize an angle (i.e. minimize its cosine) we need that the $4$ vectors form a triangle. Refer also to the Geogebra demonstration by Semiclassical.

Comment: Can u bit explain what @Semiclassical did in the demonstration ? Because all.circles centee should be at origin isnt as all r on the unit circle having centre (0,0), but in demonstration its all diff points  ?

Comment: @Paracetamol Complex numbers can be treated as vectors and we can add them geometrically with the same rule used for vectors. Take a look [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/complex-plane.html)  for example.

Comment: Yeah that i got it , i mwan geometrically what semiclassical is doing can u tell ? Making three circles and their intersection point on what criteria and what specfic points the circles centre r located /why ( the proof is basically what i am asking )